# ASUS x99 Deluxe WiFi antenna driver for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, broadcom, asus

Recently, I got an ASUS x99 deluxe motherboard. In the package, it contains a WiFi antenna. But it doesn't work on my Ubuntu system and I can't find any driver for Ubuntu. Anyone else had the same issue? How did you solve it?

Here is the info:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 15 Apr 2016 11:31 EDT -0400

Booted last: 15 Apr 2016 11:22 EDT -0400

Script from: 30 Apr 2015 17:23 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.19.0-58-generic #64~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 18 19:05:43 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V [8086:15a1] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:85c4]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:85f0]
    Kernel driver in use: igb

0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8659]

0d:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller [1b21:0612] (rev 02)

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 008 Device 002: ID 8087:8002 Intel Corp. 
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 8087:800a Intel Corp. 
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b05:180a ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04d9:0269 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 8564:1000 Transcend Information, Inc. JetFlash
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

eeepc_wmi              16384  0 
asus_wmi               24576  1 eeepc_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
video                  20480  2 nouveau,asus_wmi
wmi                    20480  3 mxm_wmi,nouveau,asus_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Memory:fb600000-fb61ffff 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth1' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fb100000-fb120000 

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

##### resolv.conf #######################

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            igb
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

- Device: eth1 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            e1000e
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth1' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/New_York (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

eth1      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x8086:0x15a1 (e1000e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth1' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
# PCI device 0x8086:0x1539 (igb)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

##### dmesg #############################

[    7.456936] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready

########## wireless info END ############
```